# Google Map not Updating By Onchange Event In Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

In Dynamics 365(version:8.2), I am loading google map using web resource and then trying to initiate google map by `onchange` event from CRM input field but it is showing error alert message:

> ReferenceError: google is not defined at initMap

I got the solution by finding iframe and then call google map.like this:

```
var description = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_street').getValue(); 
// Get the HTML iFrame object. 
var iFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('WebResource_Map').getObject(); 
// Get the element from the iFrame. 
var element = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('addr_line1'); 
var ifr = iFrame.contentWindow; 
// Set the element's value. 
element.value = description+' ';
```

I need help on this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As first step please add the code youre running.

Comment: Dynamics 365 has Bing maps out of the box, no need to reinvent the wheel. You most likely can get by for free unless your system has thousands of users.

Comment: Thanks Fabian and Alex for your reply. i got the solution by finding iframe and then call google map.like this :var description = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_street').getValue();
    
    // Get the HTML iFrame object.
    var iFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('WebResource_Map').getObject();

    // Get the element from the iFrame.
    var element = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('addr_line1');
    var ifr = iFrame.contentWindow;
    // Set the element's value.
    element.value = description+' ';

Comment: @Bibhuti Satpathy, I moved the code into the question, but I don't see a call to Google in there. Is there more code? If so, please post add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would suggest you do it:

1. From your script that loads the google maps (Web Resource), get the form attribute values (address fields).
2. Whenever you need to refresh the map in case of any field change, just reload the web resource that's embedded on your form and it should automatically call the google maps again resulting in your new location being set.

You can call the reloadMapOnFieldChange() on change of the fields for which you want the map to be refreshed

```
function refreshWebResource(name) {

    var _webResourceControl = Xrm.Page.getControl(name);

    if(_webResourceControl!=null && _webResourceControl!="" && _webResourceControl!=undefined)
    {
        var _src = _webResourceControl.getSrc();
        _webResourceControl.setSrc(null);
        _webResourceControl.setSrc(_src);
    }   
}

function reloadMapOnFieldChange(){

    refreshWebResource(<Name of your Map Web Resource>);
}
```